# Difficulty converting str data to int/float/decimal for plotting with matplolib

Tags: python, mysql, matplotlib, int, decimal

I have extracted data from a SQL database table but have been having persistent issues with trying to plot a graph between two variables. This is due to conversion issue between data types. I have first successfully converted a `list` to a `str` data type and now I want to convert it to either a `float`/`int`/ `decimal`  type so that I can use it with matplotlib. I feel stuck at the moment since I am unable to convert the `str` data to any of them. Shown below is my script:

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot
from decimal import Decimal
import pandas as pd

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='user', password='password', database='mydatabase')
cur = mariadb_connection.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT time, current FROM table1")

current = []
time = []

for row in cur.fetchall():
    current.append(int(row[1]))
    time.append(str(row[0]))

print(type(time)) #at this point terminal shows it is a list data type
time = pd.to_datetime(time)
print(type(time)) #at this point terminal shows it is a <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>data type

print(type(current))  #at this point, terminal shows it is a list data type
current=','.join(str(v) for v in current)
print(type(current)) #at this point, terminal shows it is a str data 
current=float(current) #at this point, I get an error stating ValueError: invalid literal for float()
print(type(current))

mariadb_connection.close()

plt.figure()
plt.plot(time, current) 

plt.show()
fig.savefig('plot.jpg')
```

On running this script, I get an error stating 
`ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 51,52,52,53,52,52,53,53,55,54,58,72,63,68,79,140,133,102,116,120,189,196,151,249,277,218,206,210,212,173,194,216,181,166,221,212,175,189,288,300,281,210,266`

I then modified the line `current=float(current)` to `current=int(current)` to try converting the `str` data to `int` type and it states another error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '51,52,52,53,.....`

I then also tried to convert my current variables to decimal type by changing that line to `current=decimal(current)` but I get `decimal.InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: '51,52,52....`

Any advice on how I can convert my `current` values to `int`/`float`/`decimal` type?

**Updates**: There is no need to go through the conversion steps for the current variable. Apparently, just using the integer list with pandas plotting is sufficient to get a plot.

Comment: Split your string using with `,` character, and convert each number to an int. Right now, you are trying to tell the machine "Hey, I have got a string and I want it to be an integer. Can you tell me which integer '51,52,52,53,52(...)' is ?". Nah. You gotta divide your sentence into all the detached numbers. And then, you will tell the machine : "Hey, I got a list of numbers, but they are in the form a strings. Can you convert them to actual numbers ?".

Comment: You had `current` as a list of integers in the `for` loop, then you convert it to a string and then you want a list of floats... No need for that. Use your original list of integers

Comment: @joaquin. I think you are referring to this line? `current.append(int(row[1])`. Although I applied `int()`, the data type I get from that is still a list. Therefore, I still cant use that to plot my graph.

Comment: Yes, is a list (of integers). Should work for plot

Comment: @IMCoins. Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this approach and changed the problematic line to `re.split(r",", current)`. The data type is now `str`. I then applied int() to this, but got the usual error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '51,52.....`

Comment: @joaquin. Ok, I modified my code so it uses that list (of integers) without going through all that conversion steps for the current variables. I got an empty plot at the end however. Im not too sure why. The plot output shows splines with 0 to 1.0 on both axes, but no data points plotted.

Comment: @joaquin. Just to give an idea of how the data looks like when used for plotting both time and current. On terminal, the data printed for time looks like this `['2017-12-27 12:53:00', '2017-12-27 13:19:00',
               '2017-12-27 13:20:00', '2017-12-27 13:25:00',
               '2017-12-27 13:30:00', '2017-12-27 13:35:00',.....]` and `[51, 52, 52, 53, 52, 52, 53, 53, 55, 54, 58,......]` for current

Comment: Your problem is on `time`now probably. Simplify your code. Forget about the database part. Just write the value the database returns for current and time (rows 0 and 1). Not need for all values if the outpout is large, 4 values is enough. We can start fom this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use pandas, this will work:

```
import pandas as pd 

# this is the data you gave (only five values)  
time = ['2017-12-27 12:53:00', '2017-12-27 13:19:00', '2017-12-27 13:20:00', '2017-12-27 13:25:00', '2017-12-27 13:30:00']
current = [51, 52, 52, 53, 52]

df = pd.DataFrame(current, index=time)
df.plot()
```

[image]